# Troubleshooting a network card on linux. Connected to network, given access point, no connection?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, backtrack

I installed the driver for my network card.  iwconfig and ifconfig are all responsive to connecting to the network, I'm given an access point address.  Then, I try to connect to a website and no dice.  ping www.google.com yields no result.  What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Ping your router, then an external IP address, then a web site. Failure on the first means that your wireless is not working, on the second means that your external connection is not working, on the third means that your DNS setup is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% sure that you used the ifconfig and iwconfig commands to issue an IP address and connect to the access point.

What you are missing is setting up the proper routes and DNS.